# Add items to a dgv from saved variables in another class (C# winForms)

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Im relatively new to programming and still learning. I have just made a calculator, and then I got the idea that I wanted to save the two input numbers (value1, value2) and the result in a datagridview in another winform.
First of i added a button (bSave) for saving it.
My first attempt was with: 
dgvSavedResults.Rows.Add(tbValue1.Text, tbValue2.Text, tbResult.Text);" and works OK.

My next attempt was to save all of it in another class:

```
public class Information
{
    private string value1;
    private string value2;
    private string result;

    public string Value1
    {
        get { return value1; }
        set { value1 = value; }
    }

    public string Value2
    {
        get { return value2; }
        set { value2 = value; }
    }

    public string Result
    {
        get { return result; }
        set { result = value; }
    }
}
```

And in the calculator form it looks like this when i click the save button:

```
    private void bSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Information info = new Information();
        info.Value1 = tbTal1.Text;
        info.Value2 = tbTal2.Text;
        info.Result = tbResultat.Text;                        
    }
```

I think i need to use a datatable and the loop through whats inside the Information-class.
But i have really no idea how to make this work. I have googled around but i havent found something that i understand. Am i on the right track? Or am i totally wrong with my thinking?
If anyone could take the time to explain to me what to do and maybe show me an example how to do it would be really appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What do you want to do next? Pass the info object to another form, which will do the calculation and show the result?

Comment: I have a fully working calculator. The thing i want to do is to save the value1, value2 and the result (that is calculated in the calculatorForm) to another form (SavedResultForm). I like to store all the calculations in the datagridview in the SavedResultForm.
The dgv have 3 colums (Value1, Value2, Result). This will go through another class(Information) where its "stored" and then in the SavedResultForm it will update all the variables in the dgv.

Comment: So you want to pass the value from one form to another... Read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa713401(v=vs.71).aspx) for details. If you dont want to use the database.

Comment: Ok, i will check it out! That's right, I want to do it without the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a list of your results:

```
BindingList<Information> resultsList = new BindingList<Information>();
```

Bind it to DataGridView using BindingSource:

```
BindingSource resultsBindingSource = new BindingSource();

this.resultsBindingSource.DataSource = resultsList;
this.dgvSavedResults.DataSource = this.resultsBindingSource ;
```

then:

```
private void bSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Information info = new Information();
        info.Value1 = tbTal1.Text;
        info.Value2 = tbTal2.Text;
        info.Result = tbResultat.Text;     
        resultsList.Add(info);                   
    }
```

And it's done.

Also, depending on how you want to add columns, you can do it manually, or you can generate it automatically from public properties of your Information class:

```
dgvSavedResults.AutoGenerateColumns=true;
```

EDIT:

to properly reflect changes on your datagridview, its better to use BindingList instead of List